# Cant pass context inside fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-context

I have following code in which I want to pass the context as a first parameter but I cant , tried all possible answers from net such as : `getActivity()`, `getContext()`, `this` , `getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Nothing works and my app crashes because of exception :| My Class is extended from fragment

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    HashMap postData = new HashMap();
    PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this,postData);
    task.execute("http://ashna.netau.net/A_location.php");
}
```

Comment: pass context in calling from fragment

Comment: getActivity() is the context

Comment: `Nothing works` how exactly it doesn't work? Crash? not compile? or what?

Comment: @VladMatvienko MapsActivity cannot be cast to android.content.Context Exception occur

Comment: than your MapsActivity is not Activty. Show your MapsActivity code.

Comment: @VladMatvienko my MapsActivity is a fragment which is called from MainActivity (which is Activity)

Comment: You can try `v.getContext()`

Comment: First, rename your MapsActivity to MapsFragment, because it's a Fragment. Second, please post the exact stackstrace and post the complete code of your MapsActivity and MainActivity. Otherwise it is hard to help. Moreover the below written answer may solve your problem, but it should be the aim to get you to understand the problem.

Comment: then why did you call Fragment as Activity? To confuse us?. Use `getActivty()` where you need a Context. If it does not work with `getActivty()`, then show which error it gives. It is definately other error then `MapsActivity cannot be cast to android.content.Context`

Answer (score 0):

Your function `onClick()` is probably inside an object implementing the interface `View.OnClickListener` which contains no functions like `getActivity()` or `getContext()`.
Try the following:

```
final Context context = getActivity();
View.OnCLickListner mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        HashMap postData = new HashMap();
        PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(context,postData);
        task.execute("http://ashna.netau.net/A_location.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: Or just call the context via "MapsActivity.this.getActivity()"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(v.getContext(),postData);
```

Comment: what is v in the first parameter ?

Comment: onClick(View v)

Comment: yes,, the first parameter from onClick.. you can rename it and use that to get the context from it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create application class and create a global instance of the application variable inside in it. So you can have the access to the application context from anywhere in the app.

Comment: While this is correct, this answer won't help him/her to understand the underlying problem.